# How can I reset some of the committed modified files in git?

Tags: linux, git

I modified some code files and `git add git commit`. And then, I found some of the modifications were wrong. So how can I reset them in git?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting since you mention "reset" in your question but haven't tried to do a reset? Simply do a hard reset:

```
git reset --hard [revision]
```

Where `[revision]` is the SHA1 of the previous commit, or simply `HEAD~`. It will be as if you never made the commits after that.

Answer (score 0):

If it only concerns your most recent commit, git reset HEAD^ might be what you're looking for. It allows to remove certain files from your latest unpushed commit.

Check out this link: http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/04/remove-file-from-most-recent-git-commit.html